# How can i solve this? It regards the indexing and for loops

Tags: list, for-loop, indexing, parameters, range

Write a function that takes two lists (l1, l2) as parameters. The two lists contain integer numbers.
The second list contains numbers in the range [0, len(l1)), those numbers represent the indexes of
the first list. The function has to return the sum of the elements in l1 that have their indexes in l2.
Notice that if l2 contains the same index multiple times, you have to count the respective element in l1 only once

For example: if l1 = [11, 2, 0, −3, 3] and l2 = [0, 1, 3, 0], the function has to return 10, because
11 + 2 + (−3) = 10.

Comment: Depends on the language

Comment: One approach would be to remove all duplicates from second list. Then go through the second list and for every element access the appropriate element of the first list and add it to the sum.

Comment: I need to dig out my COBOL books.

Answer (score 3):

In python,

```
l2 = set(l2)
summation = sum([l1[i] for i in l2])
```

Answer (score 2):

In Perl,

```perl
use List::Util qw(sum0 uniqnum);

sub ($l1, $l2) {
    sum0 @$l1[uniqnum @$l2]
}
```

In Haskell,

```hs
fmap (fmap sum) (fmap (flip fmap nub) (fmap fmap (!!)))
```

In Haskell,

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}
\l1 l2 -> sum [ x * fromEnum (i `elem` l2) | x <- l1 | i <- [0 ..]]
```

In Python,

```py
lambda l1, l2: sum([l1[i] for i in range(len(l1)) if i in l2])
```

In C,

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool h(const long *v, size_t n, long k) {
    return !n || *v != k && h(v + 1, n - 1, k);
}

static long g(const long *u, const long *w, size_t n, size_t c) {
    return c >= n ? 0 : h(w, c, w[c]) * u[w[c]] + g(u, w, n, c + 1);
}

static long f(const long *l1, const long *l2, size_t n) {
    return g(l1, l2, n, 0);
}
```

In C,

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static long f(const long *l1, const long *l2, size_t n) {
    volatile long r = 0;
    volatile size_t c = 0;
    jmp_buf d;
    setjmp(d);
    if (c >= n) return r;
    volatile size_t i = c;
    jmp_buf e;
    setjmp(e);
    if (!i--) r += l2[c][l1]; else
    if (l2[i] != c[l2]) longjmp(e, 0);
    c++;
    longjmp(d, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class SumList {

    public static Integer calcualteListSum(List<Integer> elements, List<Integer> indexes) {
        Set<Integer> uniqueIndexes = new HashSet<Integer>(indexes);

        Integer sum = 0;
        for(Integer index : uniqueIndexes) {
            sum += elements.get(index);
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```